# Dynamic IFrame resize not working in IE?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have some code to dynamically resize iframes:

```
function autoResizeFrames() {
    frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame");
    window.setInterval("autoresize_frames()", 400);
}

function autoresize_frames() {

    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
        if (frames[i].contentWindow.document.body) {
            var frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight;
            if (document.all && !window.opera) {
                frames_size = frames[i].contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            }
            frames[i].style.height = frames_size + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

This function works great in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE 10 and 9 it has mo effect.

Here is where I have an IFrame

```
<div id="projectModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="projectModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClose_Click"  class="close" aria-hidden="true">
                    ×</button>
                <h3 id="projectModalLabel">Edit Project</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src="" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: none;" frameborder="0" id="projectFrame" name="projectFrame" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="btnClose_Click"  class="btn" aria-hidden="true">
                    Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Why does it work everywhere except IE? I thought javascript worked everywhere?

Thanks

It says:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference 
kezcommon.js, line 62 character 5

if (frames.contentWindow.document.body) {
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of XSS prevention that IE does?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle for this? In addition: did you watch for JavaScript errors?

Comment: I posted the error from IE's log...

Answer (score 3):

`window.frames` is a native DOM collection, and you're assigning a nodelist with the same name. Somehow IE messes up with these two `frames`, which are not similar.

`autoresize_frames()` seems to use `window.frames` collection instead of the `frames` nodelist (defined in `autoResizeFrames()`). However, when accessing `iframe` via this collection, there's no `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` available in IE, since `window.frames` contains actual `window` objects within the `iframe`s.

You need to access straight to `frames[i].document` or `frames[i]` which is the `window` in the `iframe`.

A quickfix would be to use some other name instead of `frames` for the nodelist.

Comment: Case may also play a part in it. OP is getting tagname of "iFrame" ... do you think IE might be acting petty because the tag is actually `<iframe ...`? In any event, I'd not even noticed this part, and these are all really good points. I think OP should get a reference to the iframe using the ID he assigned it, or at worst, a class name instead, and store a reference to that outside the autoResizeFrames() method.

Comment: Indeed, IE still is case-sensitive with HTML tags... I've to admit, that I didn't notice that : ).

Comment: As a sidenote, also Chrome, FF and Opera seems to store `object Window`s to the `window.frames` collection. Also fixing the case didn't help in IE(10), native DOM collection still shadows the user defined.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible for OP to hook into the iframe's document's onload event? I'm wondering if the issue here is one of a race condition... trying to access the DOM's scrollHeight before the document object is ready.

Comment: I doubt that, since OP says it works in other browsers (unless IE is that much slower?). And the error message was "`Unable to get property 'document' of undefined..`", meaning `contentWindow` is undefined...

Comment: "contentWindow is undefined" could actually mean there's a race condition

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
window.setInterval(autoresize_frames, 400);
```

just to see if the alternate means of setting the callback does the trick. You might also need to put the autoresize_frames() function above the autoResizeFrames() function to make sure it exists in memory before it's called by setInterval().

Comment: Tried all your suggestions; Still no luck.